# How to fix a run-time error in ZeroMQ publisher c++

Tags: c++, json

I was trying to develop a publisher subscriber model in ZeroMQ, using c++, where I am extracting an object value from a JSON-file and sending it to the other side.

My subscriber part is running well with giving any error. But I am facing the below error in the publisher part: ( in the if statement )

```
    src/lib_json/json_value.cpp:1136: Json::Value& 
    Json::Value::resolveReference(const char*, bool): Assertion `type_ == 
    nullValue || type_ == objectValue' failed.
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is my code for publisher:

```
    #include "jsoncpp/include/json/value.h"
    #include "jsoncpp/include/json/reader.h"
    #include <fstream>
    #include "cppzmq/zmq.hpp"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main () {
      zmq::context_t context(1);
      zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);
      int sndhwm = 0;
      publisher.setsockopt (ZMQ_SNDHWM, &sndhwm, sizeof (sndhwm));
      publisher.bind("tcp://*:5561");
      const Json::Value p;
      ifstream pub_file("counter.json");
      Json::Reader reader;
      Json::Value root;

      if(pub_file != NULL && reader.parse(pub_file, root)) {
      const Json::Value p = root ["body"]["device_data"]["device_status"];
       }

      string text = p.asString();
      zmq::message_t message(text.size());
      memcpy(message.data() , text.c_str() , text.size());
      zmq_sleep (1);
      publisher.send(message);
      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: You need to learn about *scoping*. You have ***two different*** variables both named `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Json::Value p;
...
if(pub_file != NULL && reader.parse(pub_file, root)) {
    const Json::Value p = root ["body"]["device_data"]["device_status"];
}

string text = p.asString();
```

When you create **another** `p` inside the **`if`** statement, this newly declared variable is local just to the scope of the conditional {}-code-block. Change this to a clean assignment to an already declared variable **`p`**:

```
p = root ["body"]["device_data"]["device_status"];
```

This changes the variable in the outer scope, not declaring a new one inside the inner scope. Also, you should mark the variable `const Json::Value p` as *not* `const`, so you can modify it inside the conditional.

Comment: pub.cpp:31:4: error: passing ‘const Json::Value’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Json::Value& Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  p = root ["body"]["device_data"]["device_status"];

Getting this error

Comment: And if i am removing the const i am getting this error during compilation

pub.cpp:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The first error means that the operator modifies the object p, which is marked `const`, so you have to get rid of the const.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to run my codes successfully now. Thanks for your help.